# How to duplicate the same object in Python with BGE?

Tags: python, blender

When i want to load an object and draw it in the scene, i do :

```
scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
path = "c:\\.....\\name.blend"
bge.logic.LibLoad(path,'Scene')
```

and after, I use worldPosition to change the object position.

But now, I want to use the same object many times.

How can I duplicate the same object, because i can't reload the same object ?

Thanks

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The [Edit Object actuator](http://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/logic/actuators/edit_object.html) has an option to `Add object`.

[image]

By connecting this to a sensor you can control placement of new objects. An empty is a good place to use this as it allows you to position the empty where you want to add the object.